# Expose a web service via Net Framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am new on .Net FrameWork and I use the last version 4.7.2

I want to expose a web service through this api to consume it elsewhere.

So I prepared my service here it is :

```
    public UserSharePoint GetPropertiesFromUserProfile(string accountName)
    {
        //some code ...
    }
```

and finally my conntrolleur :

```
public class UserSharePointsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IUserSharePointService _userSpService;
    public UserSharePointsController(IUserSharePointService userSpService)
    {
        _userSpService = userSpService;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetUser")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUser(string accountName)
    {
        return Ok(_userSpService.GetPropertiesFromUserProfile(accountName));
    }
}
```

When i run the project i get :

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
Le serveur Web est configuré pour ne pas afficher le contenu de ce répertoire.

And when i want to access to my url i get :

[image: The Error]

Comment: A client connecting to you service has no profile. So how can you run following : _userSpService.GetPropertiesFromUserProfile(accountName).  See Roles : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs?force_isolation=true

Comment: Do you  have any specific reason to use .Net framework? There have been a fair amount of work to make ASP.net core faster and easier to use. FYI, '.Net framework' is the *old* .Net, '.Net core' & '.Net 5' is the *new* .net.